# Change default separator in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to change the SQL command separator in PostgreSQL? The default one is a semicolon (;), but I would like to set it to something else. For example MySQL can do it using `DELIMITER //`.

Comment: To write incompatible or confusing code?

Comment: We have separate SQL scripts, each tailored specifically for the dialect of each supported database. So compatibility between dialects is not an issue here.

Comment: Other than creating confusion for other developers, what do you gain from changing it?

Comment: Postgres doesn't work like `mysql` where changing the delimiter is necessary as a work around. In fact I think `mysql` (and mariadb) are the only RDBMS where that is necessary.

Comment: Better readability and easier parsing for example in case we create a function. Then it will be easier to parse as it will be obvious that semicolon in the function body is not a command separator.

Comment: Having different RDBMS with SQL dialects you could look into creating a script to replace common keywords/separators in bulk to make it consumable for a certain SQL engine.

Comment: you only need that in MySQL when creating stored procedures or triggers (where the code itself contains a `;`). You don't need that for regular SQL statements - and in Postgres you never need it, because the code for a stored procedure (or function) is inside a string literal

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that.

Not that you don't need to terminate a statement in SQL.
The only time when you need a semicolon is when you want to send multiple commands to the server with a single call, like in

```
SELECT 42; DROP TABLE students
```

You need semicolons to terminate a statement in the command-line client `psql`.
If you want to avoid a semicolon in `psql`, use `\g` as a replacement.